# raid 5 name changing during reboot

Tags: data-recovery, raid, mdadm

I left my server running all night 'recovering' after i built a new raid 5 array using the command:

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sd[bcd]1
```

My server spent all night rebuilding and I got the desired results:

```
    amir@SuperMassive:~$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan
    [sudo] password for amir: 
    ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=SuperMassive:0 UUID=2f693f45:accebaf0:70060db8:c5cb42e0
```

I tried to add this to my mdadm.conf file but kept getting permission denied errors.

```
amir@SuperMassive:~$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
-bash: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf: Permission denied
```

For some reason which i can not explain i thought a reboot would be a good idea. I did not think about the fact that I had not added my array to the mdadm.conf file. Now when I look at my arrow the name has changed from /dev/MD to /dev/md/SuperMassive:0

```
amir@SuperMassive:~$ sudo mdadm --detail --scan
[sudo] password for amir: 
ARRAY /dev/md/SuperMassive:0 metadata=1.2 name=SuperMassive:0 UUID=2f693f45:accebaf0:70060db8:c5cb42e0
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ? I really don't want to have to go through another recovery :( I edited the mdadm.conf file to include the proper line from the first mdadm detail scan but after reboot i still get the output from the last mdadm detail scan with the name being /dev/md/SuperMassive:0.

Another thing ot note is that in /dev instead of having md0 and md0p1 i have md127 and md127p1. :(

Answer (score 1):

That's is strange, I see that all the mdadm with sudo. Mayb first you need to stop the array... last time I have to repair a raid I used a live cd... let's try this:

Firt be root (`sudo -i`), then **stop your array**

> fist do cat /proc/mdstat and save it to a file to see the diferences
>   ok?

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
```

then re-create the array (sorry)

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

sav the conf.

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm.conf
```

look your conf.  `cat /proc/mdstat`

look at mine for example;

```
cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md4 : active raid5 sdd4[0] sdg4[4] sdf4[2] sde4[1]
      5762701824 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md3 : active raid1 sdh1[0] sdi1[1]
      1953512400 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid5 sdj1[0] sdc1[4] sdb1[2] sda1[1]
      5860535808 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

md0 : active raid1 sdd2[0] sde2[3] sdf2[2] sdg2[1]
      409152 blocks [4/4] [UUUU]

md1 : active raid5 sdd3[0] sde3[3] sdf3[2] sdg3[1]
      93449856 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

anyway if this doesnt work show us more info. (mdadm --detail /dev/md0, mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcde...])
good luck!

Comment: I wish I had seen your post earlier. I just did a reinstall as this is a fresh machine. However things are still not going to plan - once it is finished recovering I will update on here.

Comment: I found I had alignment errors after recovering the raid for the 3rd day in a row.. .grrrr. I read more and repartitioned my drives and this time i made sure they are aligned. Guess what I am doing now - yes you guessed it.. recovering for the 4th day in a row..

Answer (score 0):

Additionally I might add that `tee` would help in your case. So entering

```
sudo mdadm --detail --scan | sudo tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

will lead to no permission denied errors. The `tee` command together with the append option (`-a`) takes the output of `mdadm` and appends it to the file.

In the case you described the output redirection (`>>`) happens as user amir and you don't have the right to write into the file.